# Showing counts on bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I have made a ggplot bar chart showing counts on the y-axis and categorical values on the x-axis.

```
p <- ggplot(data=vanco, aes(x=factor(verdi_mengde)))+geom_bar()
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to display the counts on the bars, and have been attempting to add the counts with geom_text:

```
p+geom_text(aes(label=..count..))
```

However, to my frustration is get an error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2):

You were in the correct way, but you're missing some parameters yet. consider reading [Chapter 3.9 of R Graphics Cookbook](https://r-graphics.org/recipe-bar-graph-labels) where this topic is covered.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = ..count..),
    stat = "count",
    color = "white",
    vjust = 1
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks  a lot Johan!!! This was just the solution I needed. I see now that the issue has already been answered in an existing question. Should I hence delete my question?

Comment: Don't worry, you don't have to do that. But next time check better if someone already asked that question :).